# Error with importing some classes while upgrading Spring-security-2.0.5 to Spring-security-4.2.0

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, deprecated, classnotfound

While upgrading spring security form version 2.0.5 to 4.2.0, I've got a problem with importing `org.springframework.security.concurrent.ConcurrentLoginException;` and `org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter;`
I searched many packages for these classes, but still can't find it.

Comment: That is quite a big upgrade, classes likely have moved, changed, or are no longer present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Tome* wrote in comment, it is a quite big upgrade with many changes, but the classes you ask about:

- `ConcurrentLoginException` is replaced with `org.springframework.security.web.SessionAuthenticationException`.
- `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` is replaced with `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: I'm having another issue on `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` , My project was using constants like `SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY` , `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY` and `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY` from AuthenticationProcessingFilter. Here I'm using `WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION` so, the problem with `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY` is solved, but what about the rest two ? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

I have met problem like above, you can search on maven repository http://search.maven.org/ if you can't find it, those classes maybe replace or abandon in the latest version

Comment: your answer doesn't resolve the problem mentioned by OP!